# Gradle Build Tasks not found in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, task

I am a beginner level programmer. What I need is the sha-1 key of my project, but the problem is that my gradle button is not showing any tasks. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1gEJ.jpg). If I use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSPIj.jpg) gradle build tasks, it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOELa.jpg). Please tell me what can I do to get my sha-1 key?